# When do pthread thread variables begin existing during static initialisation?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, pthreads

I am writing a program that uses static methods and properties to get some things going before main. Language is C++11

My question is, when am I guaranteed that thread local variables (with pthread) will exist? I.e. could I safely set up thread local variables in a static initialisation for the main thread before main begins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Could I safely set up thread local variables in a static initialisation for the main thread before main begins?*

***The C++ Programming Language,Fourth Edition, Bjarne Stroustrup:***

> 12.1.8. Local Variables
>
> A name defined in a function is commonly referred to as a local name.
>   A local variable or constant is initialized when a thread of execution
>   reaches its definition. Unless declared static, each invocation of the
>   function has its own copy of the variable. If a local variable is
>   declared static, a single, statically allocated object (§6.4.2) will
>   be used to represent that variable in all calls of the function. **It
>   will be initialized only the first time a thread of execution reaches
>   its definition. For example:...**

15.4.1. Initialization of Nonlocal Variables
....

> The initialization of nonlocal (statically allocated) variables is
>   controlled by whatever mechanism an implementation uses to start up a
>   C++ program. **This mechanism is guaranteed to work properly only if
>   main() is executed.**

Although you are referring to *thread local variables*, since your initialization code itself is apparently global `static`, you have no guarantee that your initialization code has been executed before `main()` begins to run, so if you have statics depending on other statics, you may have problems.

But once `main()` executes, all your `static` code has been initialized. If so, static resources that you refer to inside `main()` are guaranteed to be available.

If your thread locals are declared in thread variables that are static members or global statics, `main()` must execute so that static thread is initialized, and depending on how you have declared your thread locals, also kicked off, at which point the thread local statics will be initialized by the time their point of execution is reached.

Comment: The variables I am worried about are the thread local ones. At which point are they guarateed to exist?

Comment: That's part 1 of the answer: _It will be initialized only the first time a thread of execution reaches its definition_ . So if your thread locals are declared in thread variables that are static members or global statics, `main()` must execute so that thread is kicked off, at which point the thread local statics will be initialized by the time their point of execution is reached.

Comment: @ThomasKejser - see edit. If you have declared thread local statics in static members or globals,  both parts of the answer are applicable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been debugging a situation all day where those variables were not initialised. Static initialisation really is a headache.

Comment: @ThomasKejser - _Static initialisation really is a headache_ - agreed. Outside of what Stroustrup says, there are no guarantees about when resources become available.